# ¿Cómo saber en qué momento votar negativo y/o reportar una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, comentarios

El día de hoy hubo dos preguntas que llamaron mi atención (bueno, en realidad fueron más pero estas dos me animaron a preguntar):

- [Clase String en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47098/clase-string-en-java)
- [Como guardar boldedDates de un month calendar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47096/c%C3%B3mo-guardar-boldeddates-de-un-control-monthcalendar)

Realmente carecen de ortografía, sintaxis, semántica y no son claras. Al ver este tipo de preguntas me surgen algunas dudas:

**¿Es necesario votar negativo o con el voto de cierre es suficiente, o ambas?**

Esto, tomando en consideración qué tan *nuevo* es el usuario que realiza la pregunta (en lo personal, pienso que ser nuevo no te exime de escribir adecuamente).

Lo anterior me lleva al siguiente punto: **La forma en que contestamos en comentarios a estos usuarios**. He visto que en repetidas ocasiones que dependiendo del tiempo que tenga un usuario en el sitio, los comentarios son mas tajantes, no considero que esté mal partiendo del hecho que SOes es una red de profesionales para profesionales (y/o futuros profesionales) pero tampoco cruzar esa delgada línea de escribir un comentario directo a escribir un comentario que la otra persona lo pueda tomar personal.

Por lo tanto, al paso del tiempo se va perdiendo ese *feeling* o el tacto de ir respondiendo a usuarios nuevos como usuarios ya establecidos en el sitio y la segunda pregunta sería **¿cómo responder en comentarios?**

Nota: La segunda parte de mi pregunta no tiene nada que ver con las dos preguntas que expuse, principalmente añadí la segunda parte dado que está relacionado con mi pregunta principal y son temas que he visto en otras preguntas.

Answer (score 4):

> "¿Cómo saber en qué momento votar negativo y/o reportar una pregunta?"

No hay unas reglas que puedas seguir para determinar eso. Hay muchos factores, en mi opinión.

Los usuarios de las preguntas que refieres, son nuevos. Yo lo que hago es informarles de lo que carece su pregunta (código, mejor explicación, ..) o si directamente no pertenece al sitio. Les insto a redactarlo mejor en caso de mala sintaxis y formulación.

Si son faltas de ortografía las suelo editar (sobretodo si están en el título)

> "¿Es necesario votar negativo o con el voto de cierre es suficiente, o ambas?"

- A los nuevos, tras hacer lo comentado en el punto anterior, me planteo:

  ¿Ha intentado mejorar su pregunta? (dando un tiempo prudencial para que pueda conectarse y demás)
  Si la ha editado y sigue  necesitando revisión se le sigue encaminando pero si tras unas horas sin rastro de él, voto para cerrar (no está claro, demasiado amplia ..)

  Una vez cerrado ya voto negativo.

  En caso de duplicados, demasiado amplias (totalmente imposibles de resolver sin algo de codigo o más explicacion) o que no pertenecen voto instantaneamente.
- Sin embargo a gente con más reputación y tiempo en el sitio soy más estricto.

  Deberían saber ya el formato de pregunta adecuado y voto para cerrar inmediatamente. También suelo añadir un comentario si alguien no lo ha hecho ya y si tras unas horas no da señales de vida voto negativo.

Comment: Como bien dices, es tu opinión y es respetable, mi pensamiento también se enfoca un tanto a lo que comentas, pero, ¿es realmente necesario hacer esa distinción entre usuarios nuevos y usuarios establecidos? Aún así, no hay una regla para determinar el tratamiento puntual a diferentes usuarios, simplemente con algunos te funcionará y con algunos otros no, algunos quedarán conformes otros se disgustarán, en fin, ahora que lo he analizado en estos días realmente no hay una fórmula para determinal un comportamiento uniforme. Gracias por tu respuesta :)

Comment: Si, totalmente partidario de distinguir nuevos de establecidos. Con cierta reputacion hay fallos de formato de pregunta que son imperdonables. pero a los nuevos hay que ir guiandolos un tiempo hasta que se hacen con todos esos detalles para preguntas/respuestas/comentarios ..